Python "schedule" not doing anything
I am trying to use Python schedule for a Telegram bot, to do something every day at 12 am, but nothing is happening.
I tried testing with schedule and scheduling a simple print("test") in 2 minutes, but the time passed and nothing happened. I even tried assigning the timezone manually, with no luck. Why won't it work?
This is my test code:
def test_schedule(test_string):
    print(test_string)

schedule.every().day.at("13:00", "Europe/Madrid").do(test_schedule, "test")


the code you show, just declares a new event.
however, the scheduler also needs to be running.
as mentioned in the docs, this can be achieved by periodically running schedule.run_pending(), e.g.
import schedule
import time


def test_schedule(test_string):
    print(test_string)


schedule.every().day.at("13:09:30", "Europe/Madrid").do(test_schedule, "test")


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)


wouldn't a telegram bot running not be blocking as well, making either the bot not run or that while loop not run? well.. unless you're going to run it in a separate thread. at this point wouldn't APScheduler be more suited?
(see also docs)

I managed to make it work! I had to assign the while True() to a thread, as @KenzoStaelens said, bot the while True and bot.infinity_polling are blocking, but now it seems it works perfectly, thank you!
And yeah, I should have probably paid more attention to the docs.

since you are new to [so]: if an answer answers your question, you should probably resolve the issue by accepting the answer. if no acceptable answers show up in time but you found a solution anyhow, you can self-answer your own question and accept that. marking an issue as "resolved" helps other people to concentrate on yet-unresolved problems.
